# Simple Swing app memory grows by resizing the frame

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks

This simple program, and memory (Private Working Set by Task manager) grows by resizing its frame. 32MB (initially) to 140MB and more if I persistently resizing the frame. Why does this happen and is this normal for a Java program ?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

I did the same for SWT and JavaFX simple one frame program. Memory growth is very slow as compared to Swing but it seems it grows steadily.

I also did the same for notepad.exe's frame but the memory didn't grow.

I used VisualVM to watch the JVM heap <s>but heap size did not change.
So maybe the problem is native memory that GUI library uses.</s>

[image]
 [ Private Working Set : 31MB (initial) -> 192MB (last) ]

Environment : Windows Vista / Java 8 update 66

Comment: Is it normal, probably, why? It would have a lot to do with how the API is reserving memory for graphics context (at a guess).  Does it continue to grow if you shrink the window?

Comment: Even if I shrink the window, memory does not shrink.

Comment: No, I didn't think it would shrink, just want to make sure it doesn't grow

Comment: If I persistently resize (repeatedly shrink and enlarge), memory grows to 140MB ~ rapidly and slowly grows after that.

Comment: [Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to get more details.

Comment: Now it takes 151.78MB and it seems hit the ceiling. It's not like growing forever.